# How to create a stored procedure including the "SELECT" in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am novice user in oracle and well I am creating a stored procedure to display data from a table, because my teaching process requires it. At first I ran my query follows.

```
Create or replace procedure p_ mostrar 
Is 
Begin 
Select ID_MODULO, NOMBRE, URL, ESTADO, ICONO FROM MODULO WHERE ESTADO=1 ; 
Commit; 
End p_mostrar;
```

And he throws me the following error:

```
The judgment was expected INTO" After some research changed the syntax and run it as follows:

Create or replace procedure p_ mostrar (C1 out sys_refcursor) 
Is 
Begin Open C1 for Select ID_MODULO, NOMBRE, URL, ESTADO, ICONO 
FROM MODULO 
WHERE ESTADO=1 ; 
Commit; 
End p_mostrar;
```

And I think runs correctly. But now it does not know how to run the procedure. I thank you in advance and expect a prompt response. Remember, I'm learning with Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var result refcursor
execute p_ mostrar(:result)
```

Comment: Please explain a bit what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with select statement inside a stored procedure, you need to include **INTO** clause to the select statement to store the values in a variable. Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_mostrar 
IS

v_id_modulo modulo.id_modulo%TYPE;
v_nombre    modulo.nombre%TYPE;
v_url       modulo.url%TYPE;
v_estado    modulo.estado%TYPE;
v_icono     modulo.icono%TYPE;

BEGIN 

SELECT id_modulo, nombre, url, estado, icono 
INTO v_id_modulo, v_nombre, v_url, v_estado, v_icono --needed to catch the values selected and store it to declared variables
FROM modulo                                          
WHERE estado=1 ;                                     
Commit; -- i dont think this is necessary, you use commit statement only when you use DML statements to manage the changes made 

dbms_output.put_line(v_id_modulo||' '|| v_nombre||' '||v_url||' '||v_estado||' '||v_icono); --used to display the values stored in the variables


END;
```